# How to filter out object from an array and then add it back again using Switch toggle

Tags: javascript, react-native, javascript-objects

My array

```
const initial_business_hours = [
    { "day": "Sunday", "open_time": "Not set", "close_time": "Not set" },
    { "day": "Monday", "open_time": "Not set", "close_time": "Not set" }
]
```

Saved in a state

```
const [business_hours, setBusinessHours] = useState(initial_business_hours);
```

The switch toggle state

```
const [isSundaySwitchOn, setIsSundaySwitchOn] = useState(true);
```

Logic for removing/filtering object from array

```
const onToggleSundaySwitch = () => {

    setIsSundaySwitchOn(!isSundaySwitchOn)

    if (JSON.stringify(business_hours).includes(JSON.stringify({ "day": "Sunday", "open_time": "Not set", "close_time": "Not set" }))) {
        const updatedBusinessHours = business_hours.filter(item => item.day !== business_hours[0].day)
        return setBusinessHours(updatedBusinessHours)
    }

    setBusinessHours([...business_hours, { "day": "Sunday", "open_time": "Not set", "close_time": "Not set" }])
};
```

What is happening

Initial switch state is true/on. What happens is that when I toggle off the switch, it removes the desired object `{ "day": "Sunday", "open_time": "Not set", "close_time": "Not set" }`. This is so far okay.

Current array state:

```
[{"close_time": "Not set", "day": "Monday", "open_time": "Not set"}]
```

If I toggle on the switch, it adds the `{ "day": "Sunday", "open_time": "Not set", "close_time": "Not set" }` again. This again is a desired behavior.

Current array state:

```
[{"close_time": "Not set", "day": "Monday", "open_time": "Not set"},
 {"close_time": "Not set", "day": "Sunday", "open_time": "Not set"}]
```

But on the next toggle off, what was removed is now the `{ "day": "Monday", "open_time": "Not set", "close_time": "Not set" }`

Current array state:

```
[{"close_time": "Not set", "day": "Sunday", "open_time": "Not set"}]
```

On the next toggle on, the array is now empty.

```
[]
```

If I toggle it off again, the array is now:

```
[{"close_time": "Not set", "day": "Sunday", "open_time": "Not set"}]
```

If I toggle it on again, the array is empty again:

```
[]
```

And it continues to the behavior that it adds the "Sunday" object again, then empty, then "Sunday" on every toggle.

What I'm trying to achieve is for this scenario:

[image]

I know the error is somewhere inside the `filter()`, I just can't seem to figure it out.

Does it have something to do with the actual `filter()` and it's filtering condition `item => item.day !== business_hours[0].day` and `.includes()`?

Thank you for your help, I am a beginner when it comes to array manipulation.

Comment: Instead of adding/removing objects from the state it may be simpler to update an object property when its toggled off/on and use that to inform whether or not it renders the timeslots.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code to this

```
const updatedBusinessHours = business_hours.filter(item => item.day !== "Sunday")
```

In your code

```
const updatedBusinessHours = business_hours.filter(item => item.day !== business_hours[0].day)
```

what you were doing with this above line is filtering out the first object. No matter if it is sunday or monday.
`business_hours[0]` picks first object in that array. It does not check if it is sunday or monday or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like given below.

```
const updateList = (dayName) => {
    const arrayList = [
      {close_time: 'Not set', day: 'Sunday', open_time: 'Not set'},
    ];
    const exist = arrayList.findIndex(item => item.day === dayName);
    if (exist > -1) {
      //record exist remove
      arrayList.splice(exist, 1);
    } else {
      //not exist add
      arrayList.push({
        close_time: 'Not set',
        day: dayName,
        open_time: 'Not set',
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: You don't need lodash: [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).